# Get total number of lines of code in translation unit

Tags: c++

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know total number of LOC, including everything included from iostream.

Comment: What is a "line" anyway? Do blank ones count? What use does this number have?

Comment: Invoke preprocessor, then use your shell to report number of lines in a file.

Comment: There should be an option for GCC which produces output after inclusions and macro expansion. You could feed it then to a utility which counts lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use GCC's `-E`-option, which does preprocessor only compilation, so all makros and includes will be expanded and the resulting code is sent to console output. Feeding this into a word count / line count should give the desired result:

```
gcc -E main.cpp | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to check size of standard library on my machine. It's just 113567 LOC by the way, when all standard headers included.